# int/string value becomes "0"/null when passed from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two activities, MainActivity and SecondActivity. While passing int value from MainActivity to SecondActivity it becomes "0". I have tried with and without bundle, tried various solution already present on StackOverFlow, but no go.

Here is my code:
MainActivity

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

    final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("category",9);
            intent.putExtras(bundle); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

SecondActivity:

```
    package com.example.app;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;


    public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   

    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabsPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private int mMedCategory = 6;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

       // String stringCategory = getIntent().getStringExtra("category_string");
    int medCategory = getIntent().getIntExtra("category_int", -1);
    setMedCategory(medCategory);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    }
    public int getMedCategory(){
        return mMedCategory; //This value goes to TabsPagerAdapter
    }

    public void setMedCategory(int i){
        mMedCategory = i;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

**MainActivity**

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("category_int", 9);
        intent.putExtra("category_string", "9");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**SecondActivity**

```
private int medCategoryInt;
private String medCategoryString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    medCategoryInt = getIntent().getIntExtra("category_int", 0);
    medCategoryString = getIntent().getStringExtra("category_string");
}
```

You can have a look at [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: This helped in narrowing down the issue, so I am getting correct values in in medCategoryInt and medCategoryString variable. However  private int medCategory; becomes 0 on it's own, is there something wrong in the way I am declaring medCategory variable.

Comment: @Ankit Chauhan, you can have variable private also. see my updated answer.... still you getting issue?

Comment: That's the issue, whatever I put as global variable becomes 0. I also tried assigning value 6 to private int medCategoryInt and that value doesn't change. Seems like private int medCategoryInt is static, and it's not possible to change it's value.

Comment: it is not static. It should not happen. Update your question with whole SecondActivity.java

Comment: Updated question with whole SecondActivity.java

Comment: ohk... i see. a little mistake... remove 'int' from 'int medCategory = getIntent().getIntExtra("category_int", -1);' your issue will be soved.

Comment: just use medCategory = getIntent().getIntExtra("category_int", -1);

Comment: No there is a difference in name, one is "mMedCategory" and another one is "medCategory".

Comment: is there same key you are using at both activities? "category_int"? confirm that.

Comment: Yes, it's same key. I have started getting this warning now "Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"  :)

Comment: come to chat room : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/164876/android-help-discussion?tab=general

Comment: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. :/

Comment: Let me start a project from scratch, probably it's a very silly mistake I am making. Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Intent#getIntExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)) to retrieve an integer value from the intent:

From `MainActivity`:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("category", 9);
MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

From `SecondActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    medCategory = intent.getIntExtra("category", -1);
}
```

Note that this would assign a default value of `-1` to `medCategory` in the event that the key cannot be found.

Comment: I don't get extras.getIntExtra as an option it's just extras.getInt

Comment: @AnkitChauhan Which Android API verison  are you using?  It looks like a really old one, and also that maybe you are mixing old and new syntax.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: Because you are trying to getIntExtra on a bundle. Tim told you to getIntExtra  on Intent.

Comment: Tried that as well, same issue. Please see answer from Rumit, we seems to have figured out the issue. It's the     private int medCategory; variable in SecondActivity whoes value doesn't change.

Comment: So is the issue still persist or solved? If it is not working then I have updated my ans with that private global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Remove final and try to initialize intent in onclick method not outside of it.

**In your OnClick**

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("category",9);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

**In your second activity**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int mMedCategory =0;

public int getmMedCategory() {
    return mMedCategory;
}

public void setmMedCategory(int mMedCategory) {
    this.mMedCategory = mMedCategory;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null){
        int demoCategory =bundle.getInt("category");
        setmMedCategory(demoCategory);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void Show(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(getmMedCategory()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

**EDIT**

Created a demo project for you it is working. Show method is onclick method of a button.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still the same issue.

Comment: @AnkitChauhan I updated my code. Created a demo code for you. Test it.

Comment: Demo works fine, and value 9 appears in Toast. However as soon as scope changes, value again becomes 0 in method "public int getMedCategory()".

Comment: Same issue. Let me start a project from scratch, probably it's a very silly mistake I am making. Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but You may use this for second activity:

```
SecondActivity secondActivity = new SecondActivity();
    if (secondActivity.getIntent.getExtras() != null)
    {
        int medCat = secondActivity.getIntent.getExtras().getInt("category");
    }
```